# Recursive previous and next in arrow key press in custom autocomplete with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have developed customise autocomplete which works fine in terms of data pulling and displaying in the page. I want to enhance it. I want to implement something like [this (multiple dataset of typeahead pluggin)](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) where I want to select or set focus on the next and previous li of my autocomplete when down / up arrow key is pressed. Here is my jquery code which populate the autocomplete.

```
  $("input[data-tg-autocomplete]").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38) {
        //alert(e.keyCode);
        DownUpKeyPress(e.keyCode);
    }
    else {
        var $input = $(this);
        //-----------------------------Allowing user to enter atleast one character for auto search
        if ($input.val().length > 0) {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: $input.attr("data-tg-autocomplete"),
                method: "GET",
                data: { term: $input.val() },
                dataType: "json"
            });

            request.done(function (JsonData) {
                LoadAutoSuggest(JsonData);
            });

            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
        }
    }

});
//========================populate autocomplete
function LoadAutoSuggest(result) {
    var tag = "";
    $('.custom-autocomplete').html("");
    if (result.Destination != undefined) {
        tag = tag + "<li class=''>";
        tag = tag + "<a href='#' class='list-group-item active disabled AutoCompleteHeader'>";
        tag = tag + "Destination";
        tag = tag + "</a>";
        tag = tag + "</li>";
        for (i = 0; i < result.Destination.length - 1; i++) {
            tag = tag + "<li class='list-group-item'>";
            tag = tag + "<a class='autocompleteListItem' data-type='Destination' data-id='" + result.Destination[i].DestinationID + "'>";
            tag = tag + "<div>";
            tag = tag + result.Destination[i].DestinationName;
            // tag = tag + "<span class='pull-right badge'>14</span>";
            tag = tag + "</div>";
            tag = tag + "</a>";
            tag = tag + "</li>";
        }
    }
    if (result.Business != undefined) {
        tag = tag + "<li class=''>";
        tag = tag + "<a href='#' class='list-group-item active disabled AutoCompleteHeader'>";
        tag = tag + "Business";
        tag = tag + "</a>";
        tag = tag + " </li>";
        for (i = 0; i < result.Business.length - 1; i++) {
            tag = tag + "<li class='list-group-item'>";
            tag = tag + "<a class='autocompleteListItem' data-type='Business' data-id='" + result.Business[i].BusinessID + "'>";
            tag = tag + "<div>";
            tag = tag + result.Business[i].BusinessName;
            // tag = tag + "<span class='pull-right badge'>14</span>";
            tag = tag + "</div>";
            tag = tag + "</a>";
            tag = tag + "</li>";
            //alert(result.Business[i].BusinessName + " ID = " + result.Business[i].BusinessID)
        }
    }
    $('.custom-autocomplete').html(tag);
    $('.autocompleteListItem').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
        var text = $(this).text();
        $("#searchtext").val(text);
        $('.HiddenSearchInput #id').val(id);
        $('.HiddenSearchInput #type').val(type);
        $('.custom-autocomplete').html("");
        $('.Search-submit').trigger("click");
    });
    $(':not(".search-wrapper")').click(function () {
        if ($('.custom-autocomplete li').length > 0) {
            $('.custom-autocomplete').html("");
        }
    });
    $('.custom-autocomplete li.list-group-item').first().addClass("focused");
}
function DownUpKeyPress(keyCode) {
    //$this = $(this);
    if (keyCode == 40) {
        // alert('40');
        // $this.next().focus();
        if ($('.custom-autocomplete li').length > 0) {
            var $focused = $('.custom-autocomplete li.focused');
            $('.custom-autocomplete li.focused ~ .list-group-item').first().addClass('focused')
            $focused.removeClass('focused')

        }
        return false;
    } else if (keyCode == 38) {
        //alert('38');
        // $this.prev().focus();
        if ($('.custom-autocomplete li').length > 0) {

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is my html where I am populating the autocomplete

```
   <div class="Search-container">
                <span class="error search-validation"></span>
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <input id="searchtext" name="searchtext" type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Find travel agents, search travel agents in your destination" data-tg-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutocompleteBusiness")" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary Search-submit" type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
                <div class="displaynone HiddenSearchInput">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="" />
                </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group custom-autocomplete">
                @*List will be populated from ajax call in function LoadAutoSuggest*@
      </ul>
```

My function `DownUpKeyPress` is for setting focus for next and previous li. Focused li item will be used for site search but I am not been able to set focus on the next and previous li when up/down arrow is pressed. I am using MVC5 for developing my project. Probably I am wrong with jquery. May someone help me out to fix the issue.  I dont want to use any pluggin for this.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Alvaro, I am not been able to set focus on the next and previous li when up/down arrow is pressed with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in `DownUpKeyPress`

```
  // for up arrow => Previous Li Focus
  if (keyCode == 40) {
        if ($('.custom-autocomplete li').length > 0) {
            var oBox = $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').next('li');
            var curClass = oBox.attr("class");
            if (oBox.length == 0) {
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').removeClass('focused');
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item').first().addClass('focused');
            }
            else if (curClass == "") {
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').removeClass('focused').next('li').next('li').addClass('focused');
            }
            else {
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').removeClass('focused').next('li').addClass('focused');
            }
        }
        return false;
    } 
    // for down arrow => Next Li Focus
    else if (keyCode == 38) {
        if ($('.custom-autocomplete li').length > 0) {
            var oBox = $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').prev('li');
            var curClass = oBox.attr("class");
            if (oBox.length == 0) {
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').removeClass('focused');
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item').last().addClass('focused');
            }
            else if (curClass == "") {
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').removeClass('focused').prev('li').prev('li').addClass('focused');
            }
            else {
                $('.custom-autocomplete > .list-group-item.focused').removeClass('focused').prev('li').addClass('focused');
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```